# How to keep iPhone app out of iPad store?

Tags: iphone, ipad, release, universal-binary

I have an iPhone app that I have started to turn into a universal app, however the process is not complete and I want to release an update to the iPhone version.

I know that you can specify device capabilities in the Info.plist file to restrict your app to certain devices, but how can I do this to prevent the unfinished universal version from appearing in the iPad store?

Is checking the LSRequiresiPhoneOS BOOL entry (in the Info.plist file) enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) and specify that you require "telephony" in your info.plist.  That would keep it off the iPad (and iPod touch too). See [Device Support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html).

Comment: I have setted telephony under UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in my infor.plist, but still my app runs under iPad. Also, I have chaged my targeted Device family to iPhone. But no success in allowing my app only for iPhone. Am I missing something.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only change this on new apps, app updates are not allowed to run on fewer devices than older versions of the same app. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider restriction to iPhone *very* bad decision - the iPad is designed to run all iPhone apps in compatibilty mode (except for obvious things like telephony). So you will run into severe complaints.

If it is about the half-done enhancements for the iPad part, then just turn those features off and compile for iPhone (targeted device: only iPhone; maybe tweak the plist file, too).

Answer (score 1):

I found a setting under Project Settings -> Build that titled "Targeted Device Family."  Maybe try setting this to just iPhone, not iPhone/iPad -- I think that should also help.

Comment: I don't think that will prevent running it on an iPad.  It will just appear in a small iPhone sized window on the iPad instead of using the full screen.

Comment: ewindsor! I know you... never realized you were the one who answered this. I should have just asked over skype hahaha